# Sqoop: How to add an extra column to output and replace empty strings?

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I have an SQL table with the following columns:

```
name, fname, e-mail, phone
```

How to import this table with Sqoop into CSV file on HDFS with:

1. An extra `phone2` column so to have the following format of output CSV record:

   name, fname, e-mail, phone, phone2

where `phone2` has `udef` value for **all** output records.

1. Some input records may have an empty `e-mail` field which results in CSV lines with `,,` fields like this:

   John,Smith,,1234567

How to replace `,,` empty strings with `undef` string? To have CSV with records like:

John ,Smith ,undef ,1234567, undef
   Tom, Brooks, toom@abc.com, 78979878, undef
   ...
   etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sqoop can take a query so in addition to specifying your --null-string and --null-non-string options, you can specify any old query to export. For you, your query is pretty simple:

```
select name, fname, e-mail, phone, null AS phone2 FROM people
```

And then you just drop it in your sqoop command. Note that you may need to do --map-column-java to tell sqoop what data type you want the columns to be since with a custom query, it won't nec. be able to figure it out.

```
sqoop \
  --query 'select name, fname, e-mail, phone, null AS phone2 FROM people'
  --null-string UNDEF
  --null-non-string UNDEF
  ... connection info and other options, if nec....
```

**Bonus tip**: some databases can export super fast with the --direct option enabled so you may want to look at that, depending on the size of your table.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know , While importing SQL data to Sqoop there is no way to add Extra columns.
But it is possible to change the null values to some other values using `null-string`. For Example,

```
sqoop import \
  --connect jdbc:mysql://mysql.example.com/sqoop \
  --username sqoop \
  --password sqoop \
  --table cities \
  --null-string 'UNDEF' \
  --null-non-string 'UNDEF'
```

The above code changed the null value to 'UNDEF'.

Comment: Thanks, Are empy string and `null-string` one and the same thing?

Comment: Both are same because the nulls and empty strings take up the same size in the memory.